# How to display an element based on a condition using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to display div element based on certain condition got from the table data using react table and typescript

**code**

```
const buildColumns: (mode: someMode,) => (mode) => [
    {
       Header: 'Name',
       id: 'name',
       Cell: props => {
           const isActive = props.row.original.isActive === true 
                         || props.row.original.isActive === null;
       return (
           {!isActive &&
              <div>show me</div>
           });
      }
]
```

Now if `isActive` is not `null` and if `isActive` is `false` i should display div element. how could i do it.

the above condition displays it even if `isActive` is `null`. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: can you try this `isActive != null && !isActive` ?

Comment: or you can directly change the `isActive`  variable.  `const isActive = props.row.original.isActive === false && props.row.original.isActive != null;` and directly add it on the div as `{ isActive ...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i have explained already , you can approach this by two methods

1. you can directly add a `nullchecker` on your component condition.

   ```
    isActive != null && !isActive  &&
      <div>show me</div>
    });
   ```
2. You can directly change the `isActive` variable.

   ```
   const isActive = props.row.original.isActive === false && 
                 props.row.original.isActive != null;
   ```

   and directly add it on the `div` as

   ```
   { isActive &&
      <div>show me</div>
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If your case is to check when isActive is null and isActive is not false, then you can make the opposite condition (It's more stright forward and avoiding messing with the undefined/null mismatch):

```
  const isActive = (props.row.original.isActive === false && 
         props.row.original.isActive !== null);
```

Also modify the jsx code for: `{isActive && <div> rest of your code }`

You can read about the comparisons between undefined and null in MDN docs.
for more details about the differences between null and undefined
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null